# How query is working and why it is not taking [_1] in output

Tags: sql-server

I have below two tables with column `ID`:

**Table A**

```
id  
1
```

**Table B**

```
id  
1  
%1  
_1  
%1
```

I have written the below query:

```
select a.id , b.id from a inner join b  
on a.id like b.id
```

**Output:**

```
id  id  
1   1  
1   %1  
1   %1
```

Why it does not take `[_1]` while retrieving the result?

Comment: Do you want _1 in your result set or you want to know the reason why it does not take [_1]

Answer (score 3):

Because `1` is not like `_1`. `_` stands for any one(not zero) symbol. So `21` is like `_1`, but `1` is not like `_1` and `12` is not like `_1`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

`%`
Any string of zero or more characters.

`_` (underscore)
Any single character.

`[ ]`
Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef]).

`[^]`
Any single character not within the specified range ([^a-f]) or set ([^abcdef]).

Comment: Right and inner join always fetch the the data from tables that is matched in both

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Like Command has following statement:

```
match_expression [ NOT ] LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE escape_character ]
```

in which its arguments are:

...

```
_ (underscore)    |   Any single character.   |   WHERE au_fname LIKE '_ean' finds all four-letter first names that end with ean (Dean, Sean, and so on).
```

...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

which means that when you write a.id like b.id it checks weather 1 like _1 or has 1 any other character before it in a.id which is false and return nothing for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT a.id,
       b.id
FROM   @TableA a
       INNER JOIN @TableB b
               ON a.id LIKE '[' + b.id + ']'
```

This will give you the expected result.